# Mouse wheel doesn't scroll correctly ONLY on my pc

Tags: windows-10, mouse, hardware-failure, scrolling

My mouse wheel has started doing that thing where it scrolls up a few times if I'm scrolling down.

Here's my mouse settings (Windows 10 Settings window AND Control Panel mouse properties).

[image]

Its a [Redragon Centrophorus](http://redragonusa.com/products/mice/CENTROPHORUS/41) so I don't really expect miracles but I took it in to the shop I where I bought it, they plugged it into a pc and the scroll wheel scrolls perfectly fine there.

I've tried a different USB port on my pc but the problem persists. I'm not sure what to try.

Comment: it's definitely not related to the settings but some physical hardware problem. That's why it doesn't depend on which USB port you've plugged in. Try cleaning the mouse or buy a new mouse

Answer (score 0):

The mouse wheel has a series of small slats or spokes that are read optically as it turns.

I guarantee you have a little ball of hair and lint blocking the light.

Careful disassembly and something like a toothpick to clean the optical path will fix it.

Comment: This worked for me, just removed the dust inside.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is : turning off the option "Allow themes to change mouse pointers".
You can do this by going to : Control panel>Hardware and sound>mouse
Then select the tab "Pointers" and uncheck the box that says "Allow themes to change mouse pointers". [windows 7 tested]